# Is there a way to monitor network throughput under Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, traffic

I am looking for a way to monitor the network throughput under Windows XP. Is there a native way to do this in XP or will I need a third-party tool? If I must use a third-party tool, are there any open-source options available?

What I have in mind is something small that runs, maybe as a service, and constantly maintains a statistic about the amount of network traffic per time. Later I would then like to inspect at which times the network traffic was highest.

Comment: Please refer to the FAQs on what questions are acceptable here. Product recommendations are off topic

Answer (score 0):

I use [Netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/download.php) for that. Though it's not open source, Netlimiter 2 has become freeware and allows for vast network monitoring. It has a great stat system allowing you to watch network throughput either for the whole network, single applications or IPs. You can customize the stat display for the current day, week, month, year or years, allowing you to monitor your habits over a long time. Netlimiter runs as a service.